# width of cell not fit with iPad [iOS]

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

self.contentView.frame.width is be smaller than the real width for the cell in iPad, with iPhone its okay.

here the code of the custom cell

```
cellContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, 100)];
cellContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.contentView addSubview:cellContentView];
```

You can see what I mean with this photo

[Click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ll7ddmtpczmv09e/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-23%20at%205.33.09%20PM.png)

What should I do ?

**SOLUTION**

use: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width

Thanks @santhu

Comment: image is not accessible, give it public access.

Comment: try cellContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 100)];

Comment: Is cell is a custom cell created with XIB? If yes then you might be missing layout constraints.

Comment: @santhu it is public photo

Comment: Override layoutSubviews and set the frame there. Most likely you are setting the frame to be the size of the contentView before it has a proper size

Comment: @hazazezan how you are initializing the cell?